# Get TestResult in MSTest TestCleanup in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest, test-results

I want to use `TestResult` in `TestCleanup()` to get some infos on the tests.
But I don't know how to initialize `TestResult` object and get it.
I want the same behavior that TestContext object.

Thanks

```
private static TestContext _testContext;
[ClassInitialize]
public static void SetupTests(TestContext testContext)
{
    _testContext = testContext;
}
```

If I can't access `TestResult` in `TestCleanup`, how can I write all the testresult to a csv file after all test finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access `TestResult` object in `TestCleanup` because it doesn't exist at this stage yet. Time spent in `TestCleanup` and `TestInitialize` are combine to `TestResult.Duration` property during test execution. You can easily test it by putting something like:

```
[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

in your fast executing `TestMethod`. Or you can check `Invoke` method on `TestMethodInfo`: https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/167533cadfd2839641fc238d39ad2e86b4262be1/src/Adapter/MSTest.CoreAdapter/Execution/TestMethodInfo.cs#L127

This method will run your test. You can see where `watch.Start()` and `watch.Stop()` are placed, and where `ExecuteInternal` method is executed. This method will run `RunTestInitializeMethod` and `RunTestCleanupMethod` between `Start` and `Stop`.

Your only solution is to combine all TestResults from your test class and then access them in your ClassCleanup method.

You can do it by implementing your own `TestMethodAttribute` and overriding an `Execute` method. Then, you can save all results in a static property - `Results` in `TestResultCollection` class - and access it in `TestCleanup` method. Here is small example:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanUp()
        {
            // Save TestResultCollection.Results in csv file
        }

        [MyTestMethod]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }

    public static class TestResultCollection
    {
        public static Dictionary<ITestMethod, TestResult[]> Results { get; set; } = new Dictionary<ITestMethod, TestResult[]>();
    }

    public class MyTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
    {
        public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
        {
            TestResult[] results = base.Execute(testMethod);

            TestResultCollection.Results.Add(testMethod, results);

            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep it mind that this is more like a hack, not a proper solution. Best option would be implementing your own csv logger and run it with `vstest.console.exe` with a `csv` switch.

Answer (score 0):

An array of the TestResult object is returned by the TestMethod attribute to the adapter. This is not something you can access. You will need to get your information from the TestContext.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testresult?view=mstest-net-1.2.0

Comment: I know that already but i can't have access to the test result message and duration time from the TestContext.